# assertEquals(obj,obj) returns a failed test

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, assert

Hmm, I have a money object that allows me to add other money objects into it.
I tried `assertEquals()` in java for testing out if my code if okay, but then it failed.

I'm very positive that my code is correct (`System.out.println` returns the correct answer), I think I'm just using `assertEquals` in the wrong manner. T_T

What exactly do I use if I want to find out if `myObj1 == myObj2` for the tests?

```
**in my test.java**    
assertEquals(new Money(money1.getCurrency(),new Value(22,70)),money1.add(money2));

**in my money class**
public class Money {
    Currency currency;
    Value value;

    //constructor for Money class
    public Money(Currency currency, Value value) {
        super();
        this.currency = currency;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Currency getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    //must have same currency
    public Money add(Money moneyToBeAdded){
        Money result = new Money(moneyToBeAdded.currency, new Value(0,0));
        Value totalInCents;
        int tempCents;
        int tempDollars;

        if(compareCurrency(moneyToBeAdded)){
            totalInCents = new Value(0,moneyToBeAdded.value.toCents()+value.toCents());
            tempDollars = (totalInCents.toDollars().getDollar());
            tempCents = (totalInCents.toDollars().getCents());

            result = new Money(moneyToBeAdded.currency, new Value(tempDollars,tempCents));
            System.out.println(result.value.getDollar()+"."+result.value.getCents());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean compareCurrency(Money money){
        return (money.currency.equals(currency))? true : false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the `equals` method of your class Money?

Comment: Also, in `compareCurrency` you've effectively written `if (true) return true; else if (false) return false;`  All you need is: `return money.currency.equals(currency);`

Comment: woops! That must be the missing link.. T__T

Comment: by equals() i meant the equals() you see when you compare two strings.. I used enums for the currency

Comment: Please don't forget to override hashcode when you override equals.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't override `equals()` method from Object class in your Money class. If so, objects are compared by their references, which are different in this case.
[Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html) you can find rules for implementing `equals`.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your tests to compare fields:

```
Money m1 = new Money(money1.getCurrency(),new Value(22,70));
Money m2 = new Money(money1.getCurrency(),new Value(22,70)).add(money2);

assertEquals("currencies differ", m1.getCurrency(), m2.getCurrency());
assertEquals("values differ",  m1.getValue(), m2.getValue());
```