# Java ADT JUnit test error

Tags: java, junit

I'm working on building an ADT for rational fractions. I'm testing the add method that I created using Junit. This is the error that I am receiving even though my add method returns the same ADT rational.

```
`Failure:junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: add 2/3, 3/5 expected:<19/15> but was:<19/15>`
```

The problem is not with my add method itself because I have used it elsewhere and it works properly. Here is my JUnit test code.

```
public void testAdd(){
Rational a = new RationalC(2,3);
Rational b = new RationalC(3,5);
assertEquals("add 2/3, 3/5", new RationalC(19,15), a.add(b));}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you think `assertEquals` works?

Comment: Have you implemented `equals` in `RationalC`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426683/assertequalsobj-obj-returns-a-failed-test